# How to get elements of first array of hashes that not present in second array of hashes in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

How to get elements of first array of hashes that not present in second array of hashes.
For example, I have two arrays of hashes:

```
my $arr1 = [
    { id => 1, name => 'element 1'},
    { id => 2, name => 'element 2'},
    { id => 3, name => 'element 3'},
    { id => 4, name => 'element 4'},
    { id => 5, name => 'element 5'},
];

my $arr2 = [
    { id => 1, name => 'element 1'},
    { id => 3, name => 'element 3'},
    { id => 5, name => 'element 5'},
];
```

Result should be:

```
my $arr3 = [
    { id => 2, name => 'element 2'},
    { id => 4, name => 'element 4'},
];
```

Comment: Why don't you use a hash like `(id => name)` rather than an array?

Comment: My arrays is result of database query. This arrays is only for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build hash for look-up and then filter `@$arr1` elements,

```
my %seen;
@seen{ map $_->{id}, @$arr2 } = ();
# $seen{$_->{id}} = undef for @$arr2; # or foreach instead of hash slice

my $arr3 = [ grep{ !exists $seen{$_->{id}} } @$arr1 ];
```